# How to rotate touch input on Android?

Tags: touchscreen

I've got an ir touch frame which is properly detected on android, but its coordinates are not translated properly on the system - the input is rotated by 90 degrees and the coordinates are interpolated accordingly.

I've tried to force rotate the screen by 90 degrees and set the `touch.orientationAware = 0` in the `idc` file for the device. The coordinates are better (moving finger in x axis actually moves the pointer in x axis) but the values are incorrect and it covers only part of the screen.

In here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564830/android-touchscreen-position-off I read about someone's attempt to change the output.x value, however it does not work for me at all. Changing this value has no effect whatsoever on the values reported.

Is there anything I can do using the IDC files?